# Prove that if a is an infinite cardinal, then for each finite cardinal n, $a^n = a$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

The proof in my textbook is the following:

$a^n = card\:A^n$, the set of all maps of $I_n$ into a set $A$ of cardinal $a$. Since $A^{n} \subset I_n \times A$, $a^n \leq na = a$. On the other hand, for each $a\in A$, the map $\alpha_a:i\mapsto a$ is an element of $A^n$. Hence $A \preceq A^n$ and $a \leq a^n$. It follows that $a^n = a$.

My confusion is at the part $A^n \subset I_n \times A$. What does this even mean? Isn't an element of $A^n$ an n-tuple, while an element of $I_n \times A$ is an ordered pair? How can one set be a subset of the other, when they are different types of elements?

Comment: What is $I_n$? the set $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$?

Comment: Based on this proof, I'd advise throwing this text in the nearest trash can.  Each element of $A^n$ is a subset of $I_n\times A$, not an element of it.

Comment: Could you tell me what textbook or notes you are using?

Comment: @Math_Images_Only yes

Comment: "Algebra" by Jacob K Goldhaber and Gertrude Ehrlich.

Comment: I can't find the book but as is written it's a serious error. The proof that $\vert A \times A \vert=\vert A \vert$ is one as far as I know and it requires that $A$ is well orderable. (it is assuming choice).